# PHP Regex - What is the difference between $1 and \1?

Tags: php, regex

The two following codes give the same result:

```
$test = "this is a test";
echo preg_replace('/a (test)/','\1',$test); //this is test

$test = "this is a test";
echo preg_replace('/a (test)/',"$1",$test); //this is test
```

But two the following codes give different result:

```
$test = "this is a test";
echo preg_replace('/a (test)/',md5('\1'),$test); //this is b5101eb6e685091719013d1a75756a53

$test = "this is a test";
echo preg_replace('/a (test)/',md5("$1"),$test); //this is 06d3730efc83058f497d3d44f2f364e3
```

Does this mean    \1 and    $1 is different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of those does what you want. In your code, the `md5` function is called on the literal string `'\1'` or `"$1"` (the difference between backslash and dollar sign being the difference in the checkums), and then `preg_replace` is passed the *result* of that `md5` call, which never had a chance to consider the string it's trying to match.

What you want in this case is to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/a (test)/', function($m) { return md5($m[1]); }, $test);
```

The argument passed to the callback function is an array containing the captured subexpressions, so the equivalent of `\1` or `$1` is `$m[1]`; `\2` or `$2` would be `$m[2]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's because you aren't passing `\1` or `$1` to the `preg_replace` call any more, are you??

`\1` and `$1` are synonymous in regex replacement strings.